# JQuery scrollTo next/prev div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas why this code (which uses the scrollTo plugin) only works with jquery-1.4.2.min.js and how can I change it so that it works with the latest version of JQuery?

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/scrollto-posts-with-jquery

Thanks :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

function scroll(direction) {

    var scroll, i,
            positions = [],
            here = $(window).scrollTop(),
            collection = $('.post');

    collection.each(function() {
        positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'],10));
    });

    for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) { scroll = collection.get(i); break; }
        if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) { scroll = collection.get(i-1); break; }
    }

    if (scroll) {
        $.scrollTo(scroll, {
            duration: 750       
        });
    }

    return false;
}

$("#next,#prev").click(function() {        
    return scroll($(this).attr('id'));        
});

$(".scrolltoanchor").click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($($(this).attr("href")), {
        duration: 750
    });
    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

EDIT:

Just wanted to make my intent slightly clearer after feedback..

I want to use the latest version of JQuery 1.8.3, not 1.4.2. But when I use 1.8.3 the scrollTo #next or #prev  with class="post" on click doesn't appear to work. When I use 1.4.2 it does. I would be open to suggestions for completely new code however I must have tried at least 20 today and none have worked. At least this works... With an old version of JQuery... Which isn't compatible with my newer plugins :( I'm a real novice.

Basically, when the user clicks the arrows in the header here: http://thomasgrist.tumblr.com/ they should scroll up and down through the Tumblr  .post 's

Comment: It's not clear what's being asked here. What isn't working? One could reasonably respond with "It requires js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js because it refers to that file in the "<script>" tag. If you need to point to another version, update the <script> tag."

Comment: Thanks for the input. I want to use the latest version of JQuery 1.8.3, not 1.4.2. But when I use 1.8.3 the scrollTo #next or #prev <div> with class="post" on click doesn't appear to work. When I use 1.4.2 it does. I would be open to suggestions for completely new code however I must have tried at least 20 today and none have worked. At least this works... With an old version of JQuery... Which isn't compatible with my newer plugins :( I'm a real novice.

Comment: We're all learning at something, and your edits are moving a good direction. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) is a good reference as it describes some good ways to improve your chances of getting useful help. And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container').animate({
     scrollTop: <value>
}, 500);
```

You don't actually need that plugin. You can scroll to an offset with the above snippet.

EDIT:

Let's suppose you have a menu with the following markup:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-for="section_2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-for="section_3">Section 3</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#" data-for="section_4">Section 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

...then the Javascript code will look something like this:

```
$('.menu li a').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.' + $(this).data('for')).position().top + $('#container').scrollTop()
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

If you're actually scrolling the `body` then the `$('#container')` becomes `$('html, body')`. It's both `html` and `body` for IE compatibility.

I didn't use the `html` and `body` elements because on iOS 5 there were some issues with that. So a workaround for the issue looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    rest of the page comes here
  </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS code for this:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

So in your case I assume you have some markup like this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="post active"></div>
   <div class="post"></div>
   <div class="post"></div>
   <a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

and some JS to it:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.post.active').next().position().top + $('#container').scrollTop()
    }, 500);
    $('.post.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Of course you also need a scroll event listener on the window to check which post is in the viewport so you can add the 'active' class to it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm a real novice with JQuery so am unsure about your suggestion. My intent is to have a next / prev buttons which scroll the user up and down through a page of divs all with the same class: "post". I don't know what the value is.

Comment: I added some more info. Hope it helps. Don't freak out because a jQuery plugin isn't working. There are a bunch of them which haven't been updated for a while.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work. $('.' I was curious what that was and tried it as it was and as .post but neither worked.

Comment: P.S. I am scrolling the body.

Comment: Thanks again. It's started to work. Kind of. I'd need to write code to add the active class to the first post on document load but having faked this using 'Inspect Element' in Google Chrome, I've noticed that it's only working once. Another click on the same button scrolls to the top of the body, not the next post. You can see for yourself here: http://thomasgrist.tumblr.com/.